# lock rename of sheet name POI java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**lock rename of sheet name POI java**

*how to protect sheet name to not let users change it*

```
XSSFSheet sheet = ((XSSFSheet)s);
//to lock my sheet name
    sheet.lockmysheetName();
```

**I want to protect just sheet name.**

Comment: have you tried https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#enableLocking-- ?

Comment: public void enableLocking() 
this function lock all sheet not just sheet name

Comment: Not clear what exactly you want to achieve. Probable what [XSSFWorkbook.lockStructure](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#lockStructure--) is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Excel does not provide lock the sheet name on sheet level. There is a possibility to [protect a workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-workbook-7e365a4d-3e89-4616-84ca-1931257c1517). That protects the structure of the workbook. This includes the lock of the sheet names but also the lock of the sheets order and the lock inserting new sheets.

This is what [XSSFWorkbook.lockStructure](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#lockStructure--) sets.

`HSSFWorkbook` has nothing comparable up to now. But using `InternalWorkbook` and `WorkbookRecordList` and knowledge about the binary record stream in a binary `*.xls` workbook one can achieve the same.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ProtectRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.WorkbookRecordList;

public class CreateExcelLockStructure {
    
 static void lockStructure(HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook) {
  InternalWorkbook internalWorkbook = hssfWorkbook.getInternalWorkbook();
  WorkbookRecordList workbookRecordList = internalWorkbook.getWorkbookRecordList();
  int protpos = workbookRecordList.getProtpos();
  Record record = workbookRecordList.get(protpos);
  if (record instanceof ProtectRecord) {
   ProtectRecord protectRecord = (ProtectRecord)record;
   protectRecord.setProtect(true);
  } else {
   ProtectRecord protectRecord = new ProtectRecord(true);
   protpos = workbookRecordList.size() - 1;
   workbookRecordList.add(protpos, protectRecord);
   workbookRecordList.setProtpos(protpos);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelLockStructure.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelLockStructure.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetName1");
  sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetName2");

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)workbook;   
   xssfWorkbook.lockStructure();
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = (HSSFWorkbook)workbook;
   lockStructure(hssfWorkbook);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this actually worked perfectly for me